# EventSource stop recieving any update from server

Tags: javascript, angular, events, eventsource

I have a strange bug concerning EventSource.

I have a server that is permanently sending some event to the UI via EventSource. Until some days ago, everything was working fine.
Recently there was an update, and the server now send new data on some channel.

The thing is, for reason I haven't yet found out, sometimes, EventSource now stop working.

The connection is still open, the status of the request is still pending and not closed, and no error on console at all. The server is also still streaming event to the UI. But EventSource just don't update anymore. I also tried to hit directly with a curl request, but he do not get any update, until I refresh manually.

here is my Client Code =>

```
import { Injectable, HostListener, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SSEService implements OnDestroy {
  private eventSource: EventSource;
  private callbacks: Map<string, (e: any) => void> = new Map<string, (e: any) => void>();

  init(channel: string) {
    if (this.eventSource) { return; }
    console.log('SSE Channel Start');
    this.eventSource = new EventSource(`${environment.SSE_URL}?channel=${channel}`);
  }

  protected callListener(cb: (d) => void): (e) => void {
    const callee = ({data}): void => {
      try {
        const d = JSON.parse(data);
        cb(d.message);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e, data);
      }
    };
    return callee;
  }

  private addEventToEventSrc(event: string, callback: any, owner: string): void {
    console.log(`Subscribed to ⇢ ${event} (owned by: ${owner})`);
    const cb = this.callListener(callback);
    this.eventSource.addEventListener(event, cb);
    if (!this.callbacks.get(`${event}_${owner}`)) {
        this.callbacks.set(`${event}_${owner}`, cb);
    }
  }

  subscribe(event: string, callback: any, owner?: string): void {
    if (!this.eventSource) { return; }
    if (!owner) { owner = 'default'; }
    if (!event) { event = 'message'; }
    this.addEventToEventSrc(event, callback, owner);
}

  unsubscribe(event: string, owner?: string): void {
    if (!this.eventSource) { return; }
    if (!owner) { owner = 'default'; }
    if (!event) { event = 'message'; }
    if (this.callbacks.get(`${event}_${owner}`)) {
      console.log(`Unsubscribed to ⇢ ${event} (owned by: ${owner})`);
      this.eventSource.removeEventListener(event, this.callbacks.get(`${event}_${owner}`));
    }
    this.callbacks.delete(`${event}_${owner}`);
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  onBrowserClose() {
    this.clearAll();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.clearAll();
  }

  clearAll() {
    if (this.eventSource) {
      console.log('SSE Channel Closed');
      this.eventSource.close();
      this.eventSource = null;
    }
    this.callbacks = new Map<string, (e: any) => void>();
  }
}
```

I tried to log the data received, to put try catch... but it is never showing any error, it just stop getting updates.

The data send from the server my be the issue, but the server do not stop stream, so my EventSource should either crash or keep going.

but right now it's silently cutting any updates.

If you could give some idea of where the cause might be I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that, my Client Implementation of EventSource is correct.

Server side, we had 1 server and a dispatcher, the server was sending a lot of update on the same channel with very short delay to the dispatcher. EventSource was considering all those message as a Single big message, and was stopping the refresh until he considered the message ended. But this was not happening, so it got stuck in open trying to download.